# Using "very" to put emphasis on sentence meaning

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

"Very" is commonly used to put emphasis on adjectives, like :

> I think you're very strong.

But I noticed there are sometimes other usages, such as this sentence I came across :

> With or without you I just feel the very same way.

Is this type of usage correct in everyday language ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is good for common language, and for everyday, I think, too.
Some examples of using "very" same way:

- “The very same.”
- ‘The very same,’ I said.
- Men do the very same thing.
- And at that very same moment!
- The very same night?”
- “The very same, sir.”
- Everything is the same, the very same as it was, once upon a time.
- I knew that very same feeling.
- He had been thinking the very same thing.
- I was only this moment thinking the very same thing.”
- “I’ve been thinking the very same thing.”
- “Exactly—the very same.”
- In fact, though, she wasn’t afraid, and for that very same reason.
- On and on they went, and I wondered those very same questions a hundred times over during break.
- Whatever it was, it was surely the very same.
- "Well we were going to ask you that very same question, first off why is > your front door locked?
- I'm asking you the very same question.
- Then he kissed me again the very same way.
- “Hey, I asked the chief that very same thing.

Comment: Thank you that was helpful !

Comment: I'm glad to help! Thank you for your thanking!